How to create a thumbstick with Kotlin Android Compose
What I currently have is
app/src/main/java/io/github/kitswas/virtualgamepadmobile/ui/composables/Circle.kt
package io.github.kitswas.virtualgamepadmobile.ui.composables

import androidx.compose.foundation.background
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Box
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.BoxScope
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.size
import androidx.compose.foundation.shape.CircleShape
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.draw.clip
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp

@Composable
fun Circle(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    contentAlignment: Alignment = Alignment.Center,
    colour: Color = Color.White,
    content: @Composable() (BoxScope.() -> Unit)
) {
    Box(
        modifier = modifier.clip(shape = CircleShape).background(Color.Transparent),
        contentAlignment = contentAlignment
    ) {
        Box(
            Modifier.background(colour).matchParentSize(),
            contentAlignment = contentAlignment
        ) {
            content()
        }
    }
}

@Preview(showBackground = false)
@Composable
fun CirclePreview() {
    Circle(
        modifier = Modifier
            .size(16.dp),
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
    ) {}
}

app/src/main/java/io/github/kitswas/virtualgamepadmobile/ui/composables/AnalogStick.kt
package io.github.kitswas.virtualgamepadmobile.ui.composables

import androidx.compose.foundation.gestures.detectDragGestures
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Box
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.offset
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.size
import androidx.compose.material3.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.remember
import androidx.compose.runtime.setValue
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.input.pointer.pointerInput
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.Dp
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.IntOffset
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import io.github.kitswas.VGP_Data_Exchange.GamepadReading
import io.github.kitswas.virtualgamepadmobile.ui.theme.darken
import io.github.kitswas.virtualgamepadmobile.ui.theme.lighten
import kotlin.math.roundToInt

enum class AnalogStickType {
    LEFT, RIGHT
}

@Composable
fun AnalogStick(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    ringColor: Color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.outline,
    ringWidth: Dp = 4.dp,
    outerCircleColor: Color = darken(MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary, 0.8f),
    outerCircleWidth: Dp = 4.dp,
    innerCircleColor: Color = lighten(MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary, 0.2f),
    innerCircleRadius: Dp = 32.dp,
    gamepadState: GamepadReading,
    type: AnalogStickType,
) {
    Box(
        modifier = modifier,
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
    )
    {
        // First draw the glow ring
        Circle(
            colour = ringColor,
            modifier = Modifier
                .size((innerCircleRadius + outerCircleWidth + ringWidth) * 2),
            contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
        ) {
            // Then draw the outer circle
            Circle(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .size((innerCircleRadius + outerCircleWidth) * 2),
                contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,
                colour = outerCircleColor,
            ) {
                var offsetX by remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }
                var offsetY by remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }
                var scaledOffsetX by remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }
                var scaledOffsetY by remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }

                // Then draw the inner circle
                Circle(
                    colour = innerCircleColor,
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .size(innerCircleRadius * 2)
                        .offset {
                            IntOffset(
                                (scaledOffsetX * outerCircleWidth.toPx()).roundToInt(),
                                (scaledOffsetY * outerCircleWidth.toPx()).roundToInt(),
                            )
                        }
                        .pointerInput(Unit) {
                            detectDragGestures(
                                onDragEnd = {
                                    offsetX = 0f
                                    offsetY = 0f
                                    scaledOffsetX = 0f
                                    scaledOffsetY = 0f
                                    when (type) {
                                        AnalogStickType.LEFT -> {
                                            gamepadState.LeftThumbstickX = scaledOffsetX
                                            gamepadState.LeftThumbstickY = scaledOffsetY
                                        }

                                        AnalogStickType.RIGHT -> {
                                            gamepadState.RightThumbstickX = scaledOffsetX
                                            gamepadState.RightThumbstickY = scaledOffsetY
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                                onDrag = { change, dragAmount ->
                                    change.consume()
                                    offsetX += dragAmount.x
                                    offsetY += dragAmount.y
                                    // scale and clamp between -1 and 1
                                    scaledOffsetX =
                                        (offsetX / outerCircleWidth.toPx()).coerceIn(-1f, 1f)
                                    scaledOffsetY =
                                        (offsetY / outerCircleWidth.toPx()).coerceIn(-1f, 1f)
                                    when (type) {
                                        AnalogStickType.LEFT -> {
                                            gamepadState.LeftThumbstickX = scaledOffsetX
                                            gamepadState.LeftThumbstickY = scaledOffsetY
                                        }

                                        AnalogStickType.RIGHT -> {
                                            gamepadState.RightThumbstickX = scaledOffsetX
                                            gamepadState.RightThumbstickY = scaledOffsetY
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            )
                        },
//                    onClick = {},
                ) {

                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Preview(showBackground = false)
@Composable
fun AnalogStickPreview() {
    AnalogStick(
        gamepadState = GamepadReading(),
        type = AnalogStickType.LEFT,
    )
}

But the resulting product has a serious problem -
It's a square in a square and the effects can be seen clearly when using it.

How can I fix this?
I am new to Android development. I am open to any other suggestions you may have.

You could calculate the total offset distance with Pythagoras' theorem and scale offsets accordingly.
Replace offsets calculation
//scale and clamp between -1 and 1
scaledOffsetX =
    (offsetX / outerCircleWidth.toPx()).coerceIn(-1f, 1f)
scaledOffsetY =
    (offsetY / outerCircleWidth.toPx()).coerceIn(-1f, 1f)

with
scaledOffsetX = offsetX
scaledOffsetY = offsetY
val totalDistance = sqrt(offsetX * offsetX + offsetY * offsetY)
val maxDistance = outerCircleWidth.toPx()
if (totalDistance > maxDistance) {
    val f = totalDistance / maxDistance
    scaledOffsetX /= f
    scaledOffsetY /= f
}

And update the offset modifier:
.offset {
    IntOffset(scaledOffsetX.toInt(), scaledOffsetY.toInt())
}


I am looking for a pure Jetpack Compose way to create the circles.

What makes you think your circles aren't? All layouts in Compose are rectangular, you just make them look and behave like whatever you need. It could be done differently, but there is no single right solution. @Kitswas
